# How do I plot the the rows of a matrix as points on a graph?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a truss bridge with the lines of the bridge showing which forces are present with different colors showing compression and tension. The lines of the bridge are connected by nodes. I based the line width off of the magnitude of the force divided by 1000.

```
A = [-0.5 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.5 0 0 0 0 0; 
-sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0;
0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0;
0 0 -1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 -sqrt(3)/2 0; 
0 0 0 -1 0.5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5; 
0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -sqrt(3)/2; 
0 0 0 0 -0.5 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5; 
0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 0 0 0 -0.5 0.5 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 -0.5 0.5 0 0 0 0; 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 sqrt(3)/2 sqrt(3)/2 0 0 0 0];

w7 = 800;
w8 = 900;
w9 = 13000;
W = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; w7; 0; w8; 0; w9];
x = A\W;

nodes = [0 0; 
         0.5 sqrt(3)/2; 
         1.5 sqrt(3)/2; 
         2.5 sqrt(3)/2; 
         3.5 sqrt(3)/2; 
         4 0; 
         3 0; 
         2 0; 
         1 0];
beams = [1 2; 
         2 3; 
         3 4; 
         4 5; 
         5 6; 
         6 7; 
         7 8; 
         8 9; 
         1 9; 
         2 9; 
         3 9; 
         3 8; 
         4 8; 
         4 7; 
         5 7];

clf; % clear the figure window
set(gcf,'position',[20 50 600 250],'paperpositionmode','auto')
hold on
% Code to plot goes here!
axis equal; % make aspect ratio 1:1
axis([-.5 4.5 -.5 1.5]);
for jj = 1:15
    if x(jj,1) > 0
        plot(nodes(beams(jj,1:2),1),nodes(beams(jj,1:2),2),'-g','LineWidth',abs(x(jj,1))/1000);
    else
        plot(nodes(beams(jj,1:2),1),nodes(beams(jj,1:2),2),'-r','LineWidth',abs(x(jj,1))/1000);
    end
end
plot(nodes(1:9,1:2),'.k','MarkerSize',80);
print(gcf,'-dpng','truss_bridge_beams.png');
```

I got the lines to be plotted the way I wanted, but I want to plot the nodes as dots at the row vectors I specified in the nodes matrix. However, when I tried to do that, the dots were scattered across the graph. Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s because plot(Y) plots columns of Y against the row index instead of against each other.

```
plot(nodes(1:9,1), nodes(1:9,2))
```

should fix the problem.